# FAA and Eurocontrol waypoints with same ID

Tags: faa, navaids, waypoint, routing

It seems that the FAA and Eurocontrol have **waypoints with the same ID**.
For example, the route between `KJFK` and `LFPG` for a recent flight reads as

```
KJFK..BETTE..ACK..VITOL.N73A.SUPRY.NATY.ATSUR..GAPLI.M25.ANNET.UM25.UVSUV.UM25.INGOR.UM25.LUKIP.LUKIP9W.LFPG/0555
```

How can one tell that the `ANNET` waypoint corresponds to the European area and not to the US? I mean in an automated manner, of course when looking at the map one can tell.

Comment: You seem to be asserting that there are two different waypoints with the same name, but the strip only shows one ANNET.  And what do you mean by "corresponds"?  Which continent's airspace the fix is within?  Because for that, (I know you said it...) look at the map.  There's no field in a flight plan strip for noting geographic jurisdiction of a waypoint.

Comment: [Why are waypoints not named uniquely?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/58773/3201)